# Guid constructor throwing formatException on apparently valid string

Tags: c#, guid

I'm making some sevices for an iPad app to consume ad send data to CRM Dynamics. During the process I bumped into this weird, yet fasincating problem.

I have to assign a Guid to some records that have yet to be assigned to some other entity. As this Guid can change I put it on a variable and create the Guid pogramatically, this way (sorry to type so long for such a little thing)

```
new Guid("31033981b158e31187e700155d094430‏");
```

But this is thorwing a Format Exception that only says that a guid should have 32 digits and 4 dashes. I'm using here a perfectly valid override of the constructor in which I can send only digits.

Well, I also tried the example in the MSDN documentation like this

```
new Guid("ca761232ed4211cebacd00aa0057b223");
```

and it worked.

So, the question is, What is the diofference between the two Guids?

Comment: `"31033981b158e31187e700155d094430‏"` literal has 33 digits. Reconsider your input guid format

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Perhaps you're seeing something else than me, but I count 32.

Comment: Works perfectly well here using the literal. Where does the GUID string come from, is it hard coded, or is it an input parameter that might be not quite what it seems to be?

Comment: I gotta buy new lenses that can decode these kind of 'unprintable' characters.

Comment: I have it as an AppSetting in config file, and checked many times it's length. Ijust created it in another part of the solution, but the line I need to work still throws exception...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it *looks* like it's a valid GUID string with 32 hex digits, but it is not.

When copying your string into an editor I see that the very last character is unicode point 8207, [Rigth to left mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200f/index.htm). It's an [unprintable character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark), but it's there. Try this instead:

```
new Guid("31033981b158e31187e700155d094430");
```

You can't see the difference in your browser, but it will work - I removed the unprintable character from your string.

Comment: A darn, so IlyaIvanov was right :) My phone does not print it either.

Comment: That was it. I never saw the ghost but I delete all the line until a few digits before the last and rewrite it again and now it works.